# How to check first char of a char pointer variable wihtout making any changes to the variable itself

Tags: c, string

For example, I want to check whether the first character of the char pointer variable is a `A`. I dont want the char pointer variable to be changed at all, I just want to check the first character.

Comment: @AdelAhmed If I print this at a later point will it skip the A when printing, or will it print the full string as normal?

Comment: huh? what are you trying to do?

Comment: A `char` pointer does not store `char`s. It _points_ to **a** (single!) `char`. A pointer is not an array (and vice-versa).

Comment: Pointers may be difficult to grasp at first, but there is nothing magical about them.  Simply examining the memory that a pointer points to does not change either the pointer or the pointee in any way.

Comment: Reading an array element does not change it.  Arrays would be pretty painful to use if it did.  Why don't you try it for yourself?  This is about as fundamental as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

The first character at the start of a characters pointed to by a pointer can be easily checked against a value.  In fact, this will work even if the pointer points only to a single character:

```
 int main()
 {
   char *A;

   A = malloc(1);
   *A = 'A';
   if('A' == *A) { printf("A was the first character\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

Alternatively, you could accomplish the same thing treating it as an array:

```
 int main()
 {
   char A[]="A string of characters";

   if('A' == A[0]) { printf("A was the first character\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Right you are!  Thanks.

Comment: `if('A' == *A)` works for the second case as well `:)`.

Comment: It does @DavidC.Rankin.  I was illustrating that you can view it as a pointer or as an array.